# CMake not finding lua in github action

Tags: cmake, lua, github-actions

I'm trying to use github actions to check after every push if my program compiles. This program is written in C++ and uses lua library that it has to link to. I tried using the action from https://github.com/marketplace/actions/install-lua-luajit to get lua so that my program finds it and links to it. So my `.github/workflows/myAction.yml` file looks like this:

```
name: compile

on: [push]

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@master

    - uses: leafo/gh-actions-lua@v10
      with:
        luaVersion: "5.1.5"

    - uses: leafo/gh-actions-luarocks@v4

    - name: checkLuaExistence
      run: lua -v

    - name: makeBuildDir
      run: cmake -E make_directory build
    
    - name: useCmake
      run: cmake -B build -S .

    - name: compile
      run: cmake --build build
```

and my CMakeLists.txt file looks like this:

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.5)

project (myLuaTest)

find_package (Lua REQUIRED)
```

Unfortunately, the job fails during the step `useCmake` with error `Could NOT find Lua (missing: LUA_LIBRARIES LUA_INCLUDE_DIR)`. That means that lua is installed, because the step `checkLuaExistence` works fine. How do I change it so that cmake finds lua?

Comment: When searching Lua **library**, the script [FindLua.cmake](https://github.com/Kitware/CMake/blob/master/Modules/FindLua.cmake) doesn't take `lua` **executable** into account. You need to hint CMake about location of your Lua installation. E.g. by setting `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH` variable (environment or CMake one, passed via `-D` option to `cmake`). Alternatively, you may hint about location of Lua installation by setting `LUA_DIR` environment variable: while this variable is not documented, it is used by the script `FindLua.cmake`.

Comment: @Tsyvarev Thank You! It worked after adding ```-DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH="/home/runner/work/luatest/luatest/.lua/"``` as cmake flag (after checking the location with ```whereis```).